# Diferença entre duas datas com tempo maior que 24h?

Tags: mysql

Estou com a seguinte query:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a21d3b/1)

Passou das 24h, ele zera o tempo e começa a contar novamente.

Eu preciso tirar a diferença entre as horas, contando que elas têm que passar de 24h.

Por exemplo, na primeira linha do resultado eu tenho 2018-09-03T10:35:16Z. Pegando a diferença entre hoje (2018-09-05T14:27:39Z) e esse dia, daria o seguinte resultado:

51:55:28 que é a mesma coisa que 2 dias, 3 horas, 55 minutos e 28 segundos

Mas o resultado está sendo apenas 03:55:28

Como fazer com que essa diferença de data fique superior a 24h?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é uma solução ótima, mas tu pode pegar apenas os minutos e segundos que já estão calculados e concatenar com um TIMESTAMPDIFF em horas.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a21d3b/31)

SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
    date_ini,
    NOW(),
    CONCAT(
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, date_ini, NOW()),
        TIME_FORMAT(
            TIMESTAMP(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date_ini, NOW()))),
            ':%i:%s'
        )
    ) as "Tempo de Análise"
from TEMPO;
```

Comment: OMG! ♥ Me ajudou demais. Pelo menos resolveu o que eu estava precisando. Muito obrigada. =)

Answer (score 2):

Só como complemento de resposta utilizo da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT DATEINI, NOW(), 
CONCAT(TRUNCATE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATEINI, NOW())/60,0), 
':',TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATEINI, NOW())%60 ,
':', TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, DATEINI, NOW())%60 ) 
AS 'Tempo de Análise'
FROM TEMPO
```

Comment: Nesse caso, deu certo também, mas a resposta do Fernando Savio ficou com a aparência "correta". Exemplo: 49:36:05 e a sua resposta, não sei o porquê, cortou o zero: 49:36:5